# Get data from multiple database in single query in NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite

I have been searching whole day regrading my problem but not found any solution , I am having two database one is **mysql** other is **sqlite** i want a single join query to get data from both the databases, is it possible in node js please help

Comment: No its not possible. Because to access both the database you have create separate connections. And execute different queries for both the database. What you can do is execute both queries in `async` way.

Comment: @Aabid is right, You  have to execute query for both db and combine the result.